# Semi-classical limit of Feynman path integral

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, variational-calculus, semiclassical, functional-derivatives

I am reading [Blau's note](http://www.blau.itp.unibe.ch/lecturesPI.pdf) on The Path Integral Approach to Quantum Mechanics. I am troubled for the derivations of semi-classical limit of Feynman path integral, which is located on Page.50 of Blau's note.

Consider an action of the standard form
$$
S[x]=\frac{m}{2} \int_{t_i}^{t_f}dt\left(\dot{x}(t)^2-\frac{1}{m} V(x(t)\right). \tag{1}
 $$
Now we want to expand the action around the classical path $x_c(t)$
$$
x(t)=x_c(t)+\delta x(t) \tag{2}
$$
where $\delta x(t)$ is an arbitrary function satisfies zero boundary conditions.

Next, Blau expands the action in following way ((4.49) in note)
$$
\begin{aligned}
S[x]= & S\left[x_c\right]+\left.\int_{t_i}^{t_f} d t \frac{\delta S}{\delta x(t)}\right|_{x(t)=x_c(t)} \delta x(t) \\
& +\left.\frac{1}{2} \int_{t_i}^{t_f} d t \int_{t_i}^{t_f} d t^{\prime} \frac{\delta^2 S}{\delta x(t) \delta x\left(t^{\prime}\right)}\right|_{x(t)=x_c(t)} \delta x(t) \delta x\left(t^{\prime}\right)+\ldots \\
= & S\left[x_c\right]+\left.\frac{1}{2} \int_{t_i}^{t_f} d t \int_{t_i}^{t_f} d t^{\prime} \frac{\delta^2 S}{\delta x(t) \delta x\left(t^{\prime}\right)}\right|_{x(t)=x_c(t)} \delta x(t) \delta x\left(t^{\prime}\right)+\ldots
\end{aligned} \tag{3}
$$
and the quadratic term is
$$
\left.\frac{1}{2} \int_{t_i}^{t_f} d t \int_{t_i}^{t_f} d t^{\prime} \frac{\delta^2 S}{\delta x(t) \delta x\left(t^{\prime}\right)}\right|_{x(t)=x_c(t)} \delta x(t) \delta x\left(t^{\prime}\right)=\frac{m}{2} \int_{t_i}^{t_f}\left(\delta \dot{x}(t)^2-\frac{1}{m} V^{\prime \prime}\left(x_c(t)\right) \delta x(t)^2\right) \tag{4}
$$

My questions are

1. Why in the action expansion, we need to add additional $\int_{t_i}^{t_f}dt$ in eq. (4)? I think we can directly expand the Lagrangian inside the action.
2. Could you please show me the detailed derivation of how kinetic term ($\frac{m}{2}\dot{x}(t)^2$) becomes $\frac{m}{2}\delta\dot{x}(t)^2$ in the quadratic expansion? I know that this is just the application of variation principles, but really troubles me a lot. Explicitly, I don't know whether we should expand the $x$ around $x_c$ first, then substitute into the kinetic expression, or we directly make the derivative of kinetic term with respect to $x$?

My attempt:
from (1)
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\delta S}{\delta x(t)}&=\frac{m}{2} \int_{t_i}^{t_f}dt_0 \left(-2\partial_t^2 x(t_0)  -\frac{1}{m} V^{\prime}(x(t_0))\right)\delta(t_0- t)\\
&=\frac{m}{2}\left(-2\partial_t^2 x(t) -\frac{1}{m} V^{\prime}(x(t))\right)\end{aligned}\tag{5}$$

$$ \begin{aligned} \frac{\delta^2 S}{\delta x(t) x(t^\prime)} &= \frac{m}{2} \left(-2\partial_t^2  -\frac{1}{m} V^{\prime \prime}(x(t))\right) \delta(t-t^\prime)   
\end{aligned}\tag{6}$$

where $V^\prime(x)=\partial V/\partial x$.

Comment: Hint: Try to calculate $\frac{\delta^2 S}{\delta x(t) \delta x\left(t^{\prime}\right)}$ from eq. (1).

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks! I try to calculate them and re-edit my post! I am very un-confident with this part, could you please elaborate more to correct me?

Comment: Hint: In the last 2 equations (v6), think about the inconsistencies of the dependence of $t$ and $t'$ by comparing LHS & RHS.

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks! Now I am very close to the right answer! Except for the coefficient $4$ instead of $1$ in the last line of (6). May you provide more hints about the derivative?

Comment: Suggestion: Remove $\delta x(t)\delta x(t^\prime)$ and $|_{x_c}$ from eq. (6) for clarity, cf. my first comment.

Comment: @Qmechanic Now I removed them! It's seems that the coefficient before $\partial_t^2$ should be $1/2$.

Comment: @Qmechanic Could you please elaborate more on the finial result? I think the coefficients before (6) don't match with (4), but I don't find the reason now.

Comment: Yes, the normalization of the potential term in eq. (1) and elsewhere is off by a factor 2.